# jQuery, Event when a select change

Tags: jquery, html, function, select

I have 2 chained select : when a value is choose in the first one, the second select show some values that correspond to the first select.

Example :

```
<select id='first_select'>
<option value='1' class='1'> Half Life </option>
<option value='2' class='2'> Mario </option>
</select>

<select id='second_select'>
<option class='1'> Gordon </option>
<option class='1'> Alexia </option>
<option class='2'> Peach </option>
<option class='2'> Luigi </option>
</select>
```

I have a filter input for the second select : when I type a letter/word, it show all values that have this letter/word.

The filter input search in ALL VALUES : *For example, if I enter 'e' it will return 'Alexia' and 'Peach'* !

I would like that the filter input search only in the list of values available that correspond to the value selected in the first select : *If I select 'Mario' and I type 'e' I would like to have only the value 'Peach'* !

I have a jQuery function which work but only when I reload the page with a first value selected (with cookie): 
(it create a new list/option with only these that are the same value/class)

```
$(document).ready( function() {

 $('#first_select').change(function(){
        var identif = jQuery('#first_select option:selected').attr('class');
        // alert(identif);
        var opts = $('#second_select option[class^='+identif +']').map(function(){
        // alert(this.value);
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });

        $('#someinput').keyup(function(){
            var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput ').val(), 'i');
            var optlist = $('#second_select').empty();

            opts.each(function(){
                if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                optlist.append($('<option />').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
                }
            });    
        });
    });
});
```

Problem is that didn't work without reload the page, as soos as I change the first value, my new list stay empty..

**EDIT :**

When I put some alert, here what I have :
When the page is load with a selected value : alert('1') then : alert('Gordon') and alert('Alexia'); but when I select a new value in the first select : alert('2') and that's all, whereas I must have alert('Peach') and alert('Luigi')

Thanks for your help and advices,

Comment: $('#first_input') should be $('#first_select')

Comment: See at jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Comment: You've put a jquery listener INSIDE another listener. You better put the `$('#someinput').keyup` listener outside the `$('#first_input').change`. You can change a boolean value inside the `$('#first_input').change` and check that one inside `$('#someinput').keyup`. Maybe this solves your problem too, I don't know, just fix this first maybe. Because each time the first listener gets called the second one is re-defined, that's not good.

Comment: you're right Amit Agrawal I have bad copied the original code, li-on I will check that right now !
@rednaw but that's what I want, re-define my list each time that a new first value is choose in order to search only in this new list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a little different approach. Check the comments in the code and try to understand it.

html:

```
<select id="game_select">
    <option value="1"> Half Life </option>
    <option value="2"> Mario </option>
</select>

<select id="character_select">
    <option data-game="1"> Gordon </option>
    <option data-game="1"> Alexia </option>
    <option data-game="2"> Peach </option>
    <option data-game="2"> Luigi </option>
</select>

<input id="character_filter" type="text">
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {

    function show_game_characters(game_id) {

        // hide all options
        $('#character_select option').hide()

        // set options for this game visible
        $('#character_select option[data-game=' + $('#game_select').val() + ']').show()

        // select first option of all visible options
        $('#character_select option:visible:first').prop('selected', true)   
    }

    function filter(search) {

        // hide all that don't match the search
        $('#character_select option:visible').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).html().match(search)) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })

        // select first option of all visible options
        $('#character_select option:visible:first').prop('selected', true)

    }

    $('#game_select').on('change', function() {
        // when game select changes, filter the character list to the selected game
        show_game_characters()            
    })

    $('#character_filter').on('keyup', function() {

        // when user filters using the filter input

        // first show characters for selected game            
        show_game_characters()            

        // then filter
        filter($(this).val())

    })

})
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JKw3D/3/